# Prevent same where clause twice in single query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two traits both of them add a scope (as a `creating` event closure) for same `where` clause, in most cases I'm using only one of the two, but in some cases I need both traits, this causes my query to contain the same `where` clause twice.

1. I am wondering what's the way to prevent this.
2. Is this causing performance issues from MySql side?

This is the first trait

```php
trait Sortable
{
    public static function bootSortable()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->position = static::sortScopes($model)
                ->orderByDesc('position')->first()->position + 1;
        });

        static::deleted(function ($model) {
            static::updateIndexes($model, $model->position);
        });

    }

    public static function updateIndexes($model = null, $indexStart = 0)
    {
        return static::sortScopes($model)
            ->where('position', '>=', $indexStart)
            ->orderBy('position')
            ->each(function ($row) use (&$indexStart) {
                return $row->update(['position' => $indexStart++]);
            });
    }

    // ...
}
```

`sortScopes($model)` is a dynamic scope which is implemented on a per class basis some of them add a `where` clause for `'company_id', '=', $model->company_id`

The second trait is just a reusable `belongs to` trait with many methods

```php
trait BelongsToCompany
{
    public static function bootBelongsToCompany()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope('company', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->currentCompany();
        });

        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->company_id = Company::current()->id;
        });
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: 2. No. But you can easily test this. 1. See 2.

Comment: I want to make sure I fully understand your question... Are saying that the ```static::creating()``` of ```BelongsToCompany``` in some cases adds a duplicate  ```where``` clause for ```'company_id', '=', $model->company_id```, when some classes that implement the ```sortScopes()``` method already have that clause?

Comment: If that is the case, and sortScopes requires that clause for other situations than the creating model event , then you cannot "fix" this, and as @Strawberry said, there should not be any performance hit to your db, I believe.